# If by any chance enemy sensors do pick it up, it wouldn’t be mistaken for a preemptive nuclear strike

Tags: conditional-constructions, subordinate-clauses

> *The secret Advanced Hypersonic Weapon (AHW) successfully completes its
>   first test flight...* [Source](http://www.hightech-edge.com/advanced-hypersonic-weapon-completes-first-test-flight/11962/)
>
> The U.S. Army Space and Missile Defense Command/Army Forces Strategic
>   Command has successfully completed the first test flights of its new
>   Advanced Hypersonic Weapon (AHW).
>
> Launched from the Pacific Missile Range Facility, Kauai, Hawaii, the
>   AHW flew around 2,400 miles to its impact location at the Reagan Test
>   Site, U.S. Army Kwajalein Atoll.
>
> The AHW did not carry any ordnance on its first flight; instead the
>   vehicle was equipped with an array of sensors to analyze aerodynamics;
>   navigation, guidance, and thermal protection technologies.
>
> The AHW is uses a three-stage booster system, developed by Sandia
>   National Laboratories, to launch itself at speeds up to 768 mph [*sic*],
>   approx. mach 5

[image: Advanced Hypersonic Weapon Completes First Test Flight]

> Unlike conventional nukes, the AHW is designed to fly a non-ballistic
>   glide trajectory within the earth’s atmosphere. This provides two
>   major benefits; it evades enemy detection, and **if by any chance enemy
>   sensors do pick it up, it wouldn’t be mistaken for a preemptive
>   nuclear strike.**
>
> The AHW was developed as part of the Conventional Prompt Global Strike
>   (CPGS) program; a project managed and executed by the U.S. Army Space
>   and Missile Defense Command/Army Forces Strategic Command program
>   office in Huntsville, Ala.

Seems to me that the bold sentence is non-standard. I'd write it this way:

> If by any chance enemy sensors did pick it up, it wouldn’t be mistaken
>   for a preemptive nuclear strike.
>   or
>   If by any chance enemy sensors
>   do pick it up, it will not be mistaken for a preemptive nuclear
>   strike.

Any connotation implied in the original sentence?

Comment: I like your first fix. I think the writer got caught up after 'provides' & 'evades' & stayed in tense, then realised they need future & switched without going back to fix it.

Comment: I think the bolded sentence is idiomatic American English, but I would make "wouldn't" "won't" instead.

Comment: I think I would fix it with "could pick it up".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original sentence and both revisions are all grammatically correct. However, the original sentence has the perfect tone for the purpose of the document.

### Expressing the subjunctive mood without a subjunctive mood

In English, we have several ways of expressing the subjunctive mood in a main verb, but most of them are ambiguous.* With **if**, one way is just to use the present tense: "If he arrives late…" Yes, this is using the present tense to describe a future situation. Another way is to use the past tense with **did**: "If he did arrive late…" Yes, you can use the past tense to describe a future situation! As I said, it's ambiguous.

The past-tense construction makes the hypothetical situation sound "further away" from reality than the present-tense one. It's a way to suggest that the hypothesis is less likely or is unimportant. For example:

> Parent: What if your lazy boyfriend arrives late?
>
> Teenage daughter: He won't arrive late. But if he *did* arrive late, it would be for a good reason, not because he's lazy!

The present tense is more suitable for agreeing with the parent that the boyfriend might be late:

> Teenage daughter: If he arrives late, no one will mind.

The **did** in the first version could be replaced by **does** or omitted entirely ("But if he arrives late…"). But **did** would sound inappropriate in the second version, because the possibility is taken seriously rather than dismissed.

### The difference is tone, not grammar

Now do you see what's happening in the article about the AHW's first test flight? The article is trying to make the AHW sound good. But it's in the same situation as the teenager: "The missile won't get detected by enemy sensors! I'm sure it won't! But even if it *did* get detected by enemy sensors, it won't set off a nuclear war or anything." The differences here have nothing to do with grammatical agreement between verbs. The differences have to do with whether the document sounds like a teenager making weak excuses.

This is a very serious matter, so the writing has to treat the possibility seriously, not pretend it won't happen. The phrase "by any chance" suggests that there's only a very low probability that enemy sensors will detect the missile. That's perilously close to sounding like a whining teenager, but it still sounds adult and responsible. If the article dismissed the possibility with **did**, it's in some danger of being perceived as trying to hide a very serious matter. When you try to hide something, of course that makes people more suspicious.

So, the writer is wise to use the present-tense "subjunctive" **do**. Omitting **do** entirely would sound wrong, since the possibility being described contradicts the claim just made about evading enemy detection. Grammatically, it is necessary to use some form of **do** to distinguish the "subjunctive" possibility of getting detected from what was just claimed. The present tense is preferable because the intent is to take the possibility seriously and explain what would happen as a consequence, not to dismiss it.

The reason **wouldn't** is preferable to **will not** is because **will not** expresses a high level of certainty—enough to trigger suspicion in the mind of a reader. **Wouldn't** is softer, more vague, and therefore less likely to come across as implausible.

---

<sup>* A third way is to really use the subjunctive mood: "If he arrive late…" But this is ambiguous in any conjugation except the third-person singular, and it's so old-fashioned as to be unacceptable in contemporary speech and writing. The most recent writing where I've seen this kind of subjunctive used with **if** was in a book from about 1920.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I think either of your replacement sentences would work. The original sentence sounds like an error to me, as Tetsujin suggests. Personally, I'd use your second sentence to avoid changing tense in the middle of the sentence.

Answer (score -2):

However the quote is phrased, it is wishful thinking at its worst.

The original poster is a manager at a Chinese company that uses nuclear-capable ICBMs to launch satellites for companies like Boeing and Loral.  The original poster's proposed rephrasings are consistent with the meaning of the original quote.  I do not see any missed connotations.

In any hypothetical scenario where:

- A nuclear power
- commits an act of war
- by secretly launching
- hard-to-detect missiles
- capable of carrying nuclear warheads
- at targets in another country,

the target country must consider the possibility that the attack is a nuclear-armed first strike.  The target cannot rule out the possibility of nuclear weapons just because the missile is a cruise missile, or "hypersonic", or ballistic.

The target country might panic, or freeze up, or calmly follow its procedures for responding to a possible nuclear first strike.  Such a procedure **might** include launching nuclear missiles before they can be destroyed by the first strike.

Comment: Not responsive to the question.